# Sum of a divergent series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

> For any $n \geq 5$, the value of $1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \cdots + \frac{1}{2^n - 1}$ will lie between?

*My attempt:* I know the numbers are in Harmonic Progression but I don't know how to calculate $H_n$. However, I tried by approximately calculating the area under the curve of the subsequent rectangles formed $1\cdot1 + 1\cdot\frac{1}{2} + 1\cdot\frac{1}{3} + \cdots$ and so on) but I am still not any closer to the answer. Could anybody give some inputs?

Comment: Why did you titled your question "sum of a divergent series"? The series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n - 1}$ can be trivially shown to converge absolutely with a ratio test: $$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|= \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{2^n -1}{2^{n+1} -1} = \frac{1}{2} < 1.$$

Comment: But the nth term of the series is not 1/ ($2^n$ -1). It's just some rth term till which we have to calculate the value.

Answer (score 1):

You can compare the area of the susbequent rentangles with the area under the graph of function $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ to find following inequalities:

$$ \int_1^{2^n}\frac{1}{x}dx  < \sum_{k=1}^{2^n-1} \frac{1}{k} < 1 + \int_1^{2^n-1}\frac{1}{x}dx$$
That is
$$ n \ln 2   < \sum_{k=1}^{2^n-1} \frac{1}{k} < 1 + \ln(2^n-1) = n\ln 2 + 1 + \ln(1-2^{-n})$$
Which gives an approximation that is good enough for most purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Note that 
$$\sum^{2^{n}-1}_{i=1}\frac{1}{i}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sum^{2^{k}-1}_{i=2^{k-1}}\frac{1}{i}$$
And thus we find
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sum^{2^{k}-1}_{i=2^{k-1}}\frac{1}{i}\leq\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sum^{2^{k}-1}_{i=2^{k-1}}\frac{1}{2^{k-1}}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}2^{k-1}\frac{1}{2^{k-1}}=n.$$
Also
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sum^{2^{k}-1}_{i=2^{k-1}}\frac{1}{i}\geq\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sum^{2^{k}-1}_{i=2^{k-1}}\frac{1}{2^{k}}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}2^{k-1}\frac{1}{2^{k}}=\frac{1}{2}n.$$
Hence $\frac{1}{2}n\leq H_{n}\leq n.$$
Obviously, there are sharper bounds, but without any context I'm not sure how sharp you need them to be.